Bash Script for Docker Image Cleanup
I’ve been working on a bash script to clean up old Docker images while keeping the latest tag for each repository and skipping images currently in use. I’m sharing the script below and would appreciate any suggestions on how to improve its efficiency, readability, or adherence to best practices. I would also love feedback on any edge cases I might have missed.
Here’s the script:
#!/bin/bash

DRY_RUN=true

IN_USE_IMAGES=$(docker ps --format "{{.Image}}" | xargs -I{} docker inspect --format '{{.Id}}' {} | cut -d: -f2)

IMAGE_LIST=$(docker images --format "{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}} {{.ID}} {{.CreatedAt}}" | sort -t' ' -k1,1 -k3,3r -k4,4r)

declare -A LATEST_TAGS

while read -r line; do
    REPO_TAG=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $1}')
    IMAGE_ID=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $2}')
    CREATED_AT=$(echo "$line" | awk '{print $3" "$4" "$5" "$6}')

    REPO_NAME=$(echo "$REPO_TAG" | cut -d':' -f1)

    if echo "$IN_USE_IMAGES" | grep -qw "$IMAGE_ID"; then
        continue
    fi

    if [[ -z "${LATEST_TAGS[$REPO_NAME]}" ]]; then
        LATEST_TAGS[$REPO_NAME]=$IMAGE_ID
        continue
    fi

    CLEANED_DATE=$(echo "${CREATED_AT}" | sed 's/ UTC//')
    IMAGE_DATE=$(date -d "${CLEANED_DATE}" +%s 2>/dev/null)
    CURRENT_DATE=$(date +%s)

    if [[ -z "$IMAGE_DATE" ]]; then
        continue
    fi

    AGE_DAYS=$(( (CURRENT_DATE - IMAGE_DATE) / 86400 ))

    if [ "$AGE_DAYS" -gt 3 ]; then
        if [ "$DRY_RUN" = true ]; then
            echo "Would delete image $IMAGE_ID ($REPO_TAG) created $AGE_DAYS days ago."
        else
            docker rmi "$IMAGE_ID"
        fi
    fi

done <<< "$IMAGE_LIST"

Example output with dry run:
root@server:~# ./script.sh
Error: No such object: registry.example.com/repo/products/app:merchant.staging.1.7.13
Error: No such object: registry.example.com/repo/products/app:customer.staging.1.4.6
Would delete image c02cf39d3dba (gcr.io/example/cadvisor:latest) created 268 days ago.
Would delete image 71dc9668b154 (prom/node-exporter:latest) created 134 days ago.
Would delete image 6a22698eab0e (python:3.9-slim) created 38 days ago.
Would delete image 4baa2e5aa1c9 (registry.example.com/repo/products/app:production-finance-v1.4.0) created 28 days ago.
Would delete image 90e5f1082b26 (registry.example.com/repo/products/app:production-finance-v1.2.0) created 91 days ago.
Would delete image 2333813ecdbb (registry.example.com/repo/products/app:production-v1.1.22) created 106 days ago.
Would delete image 587f3ff87335 (registry.example.com/repo/products/app:staging-v1.20.31) created 28 days ago.
Would delete image 587f3ff87335 (registry.example.com/repo/products/app:staging-v1.20.32) created 28 days ago.
Would delete image f17dfd3f8776 (registry.example.com/repo/products/app:staging-v1.20.30) created 30 days ago.
Would delete image f17dfd3f8776 (registry.example.com/repo/products/app:staging-v1.20.18) created 30 days ago.
Would delete image 89defed4e655 (registry.example.com/repo/products/app:staging-v1.21.4) created 23 days ago.
Would delete image ee2c9dd1668c (registry.example.com/repo/products/app:staging-v1.19.24) created 49 days ago.
Would delete image 90e5f1082b26 (registry.example.com/repo/products/app:staging-v1.17.0) created 91 days ago.
Would delete image 4baa2e5aa1c9 (registry.example.com/repo/products/app:staging-v1.20.36) created 28 days ago.
Would delete image 2333813ecdbb (registry.example.com/repo/products/app:staging-v1.16.8) created 106 days ago.
Would delete image 90e5f1082b26 (registry.example.com/repo/products/app:staging-v1.17.7) created 91 days ago.
Would delete image 2333813ecdbb (registry.example.com/repo/products/app:staging-v1.15.27) created 106 days ago.
Would delete image 2333813ecdbb (registry.example.com/repo/products/app:staging-v1.15.30) created 106 days ago.
Would delete image 57c802036fb5 (registry.example.com/repo/products/app:staging-v1.16.8) created 99 days ago.
Would delete image 526e7b9887c0 (registry.example.com/repo/products/app:staging-v1.19.54) created 38 days ago.
Would delete image a9e425d4a4c6 (registry.example.com/repo/products/app:staging-v1.16.8) created 106 days ago.
Would delete image a9e425d4a4c6 (registry.example.com/repo/products/app:staging-v1.15.27) created 106 days ago.
Would delete image 706e72fa4a64 (registry.example.com/repo/products/app:staging-v1.22.31) created 8 days ago.
Would delete image 69912743e021 (registry.example.com/repo/products/app:staging-v1.16.8) created 99 days ago.
Would delete image 4404b651cf08 (registry.example.com/repo/products/app:staging-v1.22.29) created 8 days ago.
Would delete image 6e435c33fdb0 (registry.example.com/repo/products/app:<none>) created 6 days ago.
Would delete image 324afd1d63a5 (registry.example.com/repo/products/app:<none>) created 7 days ago.
Would delete image d8594896d6ca (registry.example.com/repo/products/app:<none>) created 127 days ago.
Would delete image 87fbee245267 (registry.example.com/repo/products/app:merchant.staging.1.7.3) created 6 days ago.
Would delete image 8bcedd565583 (registry.example.com/repo/products/app:merchant.staging.1.7.4) created 6 days ago.
Would delete image 1dbe0e931976 (registry.example.com/docker-cache/prom/node-exporter:v1.3.1) created 1086 days ago.
root@server:~#

Regarding those two no such object error, I grepped them in the images list and there are no images matching, I think some containers are using these but we don't have the images if I'm not being wrong:
root@server:~# docker images | grep merchant.staging.1.7.13
root@server:~# docker images | grep customer.staging.1.4.6

root@server:~# docker ps | grep merchant.staging.1.7.13
931e52807265   registry.example.com/repo/products/app:merchant.staging.1.7.13                                           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   39 minutes ago      Up 39 minutes                   4300/tcp                                                                                                                                                                                     app_merchant_app_merchant.1.sdxy7wl8fnt7yanhri1ymxq5f
root@server:~# docker ps | grep customer.staging.1.4.6
01950400f703   registry.example.com/repo/products/app:customer.staging.1.4.6                                            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   20 hours ago        Up 20 hours                    4200/tcp                                                                                                                                                                                     app_customer_app_customer.1.sbwfxjznw

The script has a DRY_RUN mode to simulate deletions. Any advice on improving its handling of date parsing, array usage, or making it more robust would be greatly appreciated!

Don't use all upper case for non-exported variable names, see correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization.

Please [edit] your question to provide sample input (a few lines of IMAGE_LIST content) as you may be able to replace the first 4 lines of your loop with while read -r repo_tag image_id created_at depending on that content.

Regarding CURRENT_DATE=$(date +%s) - do you really need to do that inside the loop rather than doing it once before the loop starts?

@EdMorton Sure I will edit the post to add the input, but overall do you think the mechanism I'm using to delete the old images and keep the latest one before the one that is now being used is correct? I have a vague feeling that I may be complicating it, thank you Ed.

@EdMorton Added some sample output.

If you also add the input that produced that output (i.e. the contents of IN_USE_IMAGES and IMAGE_LIST when you ran the script to produce the sample output) then we can start to help you. We shouldn't need a scroll bar to read the input or output though, less than 10 lines should be plenty otherwise it gets hard to read/understand the data.

Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. What to do after the question has been answered.

@pacmaninbw Got it, thank you for the editing.

I don't see where DRY_RUN gets set to anything but true.  If we arrange that its value is either true or false, we could simply execute it rather than comparing:
if $dry_run
then
   echo …

Note that I changed it to lower-case, to avoid conflict/confusion with environment variables (which convention says are written in all-caps).

Is $IMAGE_ID really a regular expression?  If not, then perhaps grep -qw "$IMAGE_ID" should be using -F.
